# Trying to count points with Easeljs in javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, createjs, counting

Hi I'm trying to count my points in a game. I just started with javascript and working with CreateJS. My problem is that I don't know how I can use a Ticker and Click Event at the same time. It doesn't work...

```js
function init(){
 
 var stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");
 stage.mouseEventsEnabled = true;

    createjs.Ticker.interval = 1500;
 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
 
 var statPoint = new createjs.Text("Punkte:", "bold 20px Arial",     "#000000");
 statPoint.x = 750;
 
 var currentPoints = new createjs.Text("0", "20px Arial", "#000000");
 currentPoints.x= 850;
 
 var victim = new createjs.Bitmap("Opfer.png");
 victim.scaleX = 0.4;
 victim.scaleY = 0.4;
 
 stage.addChild(statPoint);
 stage.addChild(currentPoints);
 stage.addChild(victim);

    victim.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
 
 function handleTick(event){
  victim.x = 850*Math.random();
  victim.y = 550*Math.random();
  stage.update();
}
 function handleClick(event){
  currentPoints.text = parseInt(currentPoints.text + 1);
 }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding the click event in your tick? This adds the listener over and over unnecessarily. You should add it once in your initialize. I also don't recommend the approach of calling handleTick() again if the number you get is out of range - since it results in an extra `stage.update()` which can be expensive. Why not just use Math.random() * 850?

Comment: Yes you're right. I changed it, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably dealing with scope issues. You have defined your `victim` and `currentPoints` variables using `var` **inside** the init method, so it is only available there. This means your `handleTick` and `handleClick` methods can not access those variables. You likely have undefined errors in your console.

Change the variables to be declared outside of the init method, and they will be accessible in the handler methods.

```
var currentPoints, victim;
function init() {
    // Other code
    currentPoints = values;
    victim = value;
}
```